# Error compiling template: Component template requires a root element, rather than just text in vue.js with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, npm

I am Learner in Vuejs with laravel, i created a fresh project in laravel, with vue.js frontend. but after run command php artisan serve, when i run project on webbrowser. output is blank. i checked network console, there is also the output showing in example component is blank. please help me to find my mistake.

web.php

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
```

welcome.blade.php

```
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
            <title>Laravel Vue</title>
    
            <!-- Fonts -->
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app">
                <example-component> </example-component>
                <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

ExampleComponent.vue

```
    <script>
    
    Vue.component('example-component', {
     
      template: `This is the homepage`
    })
    
    new Vue({
         el: '#app'
          })
    </script>
```

app.js

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
    
    Vue.use(VueRouter)
    
    require('./bootstrap');
    
    window.Vue = require('vue');
    
    alert('Alert');
    Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
Vue.component('example-component', {
  template: `<div id="app">This is the homepage</div>`
})
```

You have to wrap the template content in a parent element, such as `<div> </div>`. If not Vue will show an error, explaining that every component must have a single root element.